# facebook development : using login written by text instead of login button

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-login

Everyone.  hello.

I have a question. 
Now i am studying about facebook development page.
and then, i want to change facebook button to login(text).

the source of my fb button is

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" data-auto-logout-link="true" data-show-faces="false" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></fb:login-button>
```

thank you.^-^

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly, you want to replace the login button with simple text (a link?).

The url to start the login flow is as follows: `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=$your_app_id&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=YOUR_PERMISSIONS`
Of course, this doesn't even bring you half way there (this type of login has a code as a reponse. You have to exchange the code for a token, and then the token for another token with "long expiry" (or that doesn't expire. Depending on the latest changes on Facebook's side).

This is something I retrieved for you that is addressing the JS login you're using http://giacomofurlan.name/my-experiments/login-to-your-website-via-facebook-using-javascript-and-php (random pick, but I see that the post is recent, and that it's using the last version of the PHP SDK Library).

If for some reason you don't like AJAX, you can do the same thing  and achieve the same result with PHP only. Here's the link to the guide "How to Manually Build a Login Flow" https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.0